# MidiManager.getDevices() returns an empty list with a synth connected directly via USB

Tags: java, android, midi

I'm writing an Android app (using android.media.midi) to control a Roland Juno-G synth connected via USB. It works when I connect the android device (Moto G5S) to the synth via a Roland UM-ONE interface to the DIN sockets on the synth. But when I connect the android device directly to the USB socket using a printer-style cable, MidiManager.getDevices() returns an empty list.
I am aware that for this to work the Juno-G needs to be configured to transmit MIDI over the USB interface and have made that configuration, and indeed this works with other apps I've tried.

```
midiManager = (MidiManager) getSystemService(MIDI_SERVICE);
    if (midiManager == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No MIDI service.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
midiDeviceInfos = midiManager.getDevices();
    if (midiDeviceInfos.length == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No MIDI devices found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you clarify your question. Maybe are you asking why? Or do you want a workaround? About the cause, I don't have a Juno-G, but the Roland product page [offers a driver download](https://www.roland.com/es-es/products/juno-g/downloads/) for Windows and macOS. If the product is not USB MIDI standards compliant, it won't work without a specific driver for the device.

Comment: Pedro: thanks for that. 1) to clarify, I need getDevices() to return info for the Juno-G so that the rest of the app then works - I've only shown some of the start-up code above. 2) I have raised a support question with Roland as to standards compliance, but I had thought that, given other Android apps work ok to the USB interface, there need not be anything specific by way of driver needed. I may need to check whether other apps that do work actually use android.media.midi.